# Video compression from client side before uploading

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to get a compressed video before uploading it to the server in react. I tried bellow method but it does not work. In the code bellow I am getting a delayed stream and also if I get stream than also it is not working. Also I am not getting event.data at media recorder onloaddata.

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react'

function Test2() {
    const [file, setFile] = useState(null)
    const [compressedFile, setCompressedFile] = useState(null)
    const [mediaStream, setMediaStream] = useState(null)
    const videoRef = useRef(null)
    const canvasRef = useRef(null)

    const handleFileSelection = (event) => {
        setFile(event.target.files[0])
    }


    const handleCompression = async () => {
        const videoUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file)

        const video = document.createElement('video')

        video.src = videoUrl

        
        video.onloadedmetadata = new Promise( () => {
            console.log('first')
            console.log(video)
            const stream = video.captureStream(25)
            setMediaStream(stream)
            console.log('stream', stream)
        })


        console.log('00', mediaStream)
        let temp = mediaStream
        console.log('temp',temp)
        const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(temp)
        console.log('00', mediaRecorder)

        const chunks = []


        mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = new Promise((event) => {
            chunks.push(event.data)
            console.log('gggeve',event.data)
            console.log('chulk',chunks)
        })

        mediaRecorder.start()

        await new Promise((resolve) => (mediaRecorder.onstop = resolve))

        const recordedBlob = new Blob(chunks, { type: 'video/mp4' })
        setCompressedFile(URL.createObjectURL(recordedBlob))
        console.log('ff::', chunks)
    }

    return (
        <>
            <input type="file" onChange={handleFileSelection} />
            <button onClick={handleCompression}>Compress</button>
            <video ref={videoRef} src={file} autoPlay loop />
            {console.log('0', compressedFile)}
            {compressedFile && <a href={compressedFile}>Link to Compressed Video</a>}
        </>
    )
}

export default Test2
```

Comment: Can you give more details what "not working" means? Are there error messages on the console? Are all functions even called? Does it work for short videos?

Comment: Getting this error: Failed to construct media recorder: parameter 1 is not of type: 'mediaStream'.

here is codeSandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-tess-uftjxb

Comment: Also if I pass a media Stream in media recorder than I am getting chunk as undefined

Comment: Update your question with this information, so people don't have to read the whole conversation. Have you googled that error message? Have you attempted any solutions?

Comment: I did googled the error but found nothing concrete.